# How to dynamically change background color of a <select> element with React and Tailwind?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jsx, tailwind-css

I'm doing a React.js component with Tailwind CSS. What I want to do is to change the background color of the select element depending on the option selected. This is what I have tried:

```
import { useState } from "react";

export function Options() {
  const [selectedColor, setSelectedColor] = useState(""); 

  const handleSelectChange = (e) => {
    setSelectedColor(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
      <select
        className={`bg-${selectedColor}-200`}
        onChange={handleSelectChange}
        value={selectedColor}
      >
        <option value="">Select a color</option>
        <option value="red">Red</option>
        <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
      </select>
  );
}
```

I know those classes exist in Tailwind CSS. So what am I missing?

I checked if it was something about my tailwind configuration but seems like everything is OK. I have added other styles and they show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation (https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#class-detection-in-depth) you cannot use `bg-${selectedColor}-200`.

You have two options:

1)
Change your `<option>` parts to something like this:

```
<option value="bg-red-200">Red</option>
<option value="bg-yellow-200">Yellow</option>
```

2. 

Add the values `bg-red-200` and `bg-yellow-200` (https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes) to your safelist

```
  safelist: [
    'bg-red-200',
    'bg-yellow-200'
  ]
```